# Quickbook PHP API select item got Invalid account type used error

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using the last version of [Quickbooks V3 PHP SDK](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK). I would like to check whether the item exists before I create the item. However, I got an error back to me when the item doesn't exist. 
Here is my code for selecting item:

```
$itemquery = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Name='itemName'");
```

Here is the error message:

> Invalid account type usedInvalid account type: For an inventory product, the inventory asset account must have Account Type: 'Other Current Asset' and Detail Type: 'Inventory.'

I have checked my inventory asset account setting. It is exactly the same with what the error detail said.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Any chance you could post your request's body?

Comment: @Kisaragi The request body is created by the package. I can get the item response back if the item exists on QB by using `$itemquery = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Name='itemName'");`. So, I don't think the error is because of the request's body.